# Как сделать так, чтобы скрипт активировался только когда нужно?

Tags: javascript

Есть многостраничный сайт.
На одной из них необходимо выполнить JS-скрипт, прилагаю ниже.
При переходе на любую другую страницу возникает ошибка, к примеру `Cannot set property 'onclick' of null`.
Возникает она по причине, что браузер не нашел соответствующего элемента, который указан в скрипте.

Вот тут и возникает вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы скрипт не искал элемент, когда его не надо искать, ведь функционал данного скрипта реализован на другой странице, на других же он просто не востребован.
Не хотелось бы привязывать скрипт к ссылке, т.к. страниц, где используется скрипт (он в карточке товара) более 600.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
document.querySelector(".show-text").onclick = function(){
    var r = document.querySelector(".seo-text").classList.toggle("move");
    this.textContent = r ? "Заезд" : "Въезд";
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(document.querySelector(".show-text") || {}).onclick = function(){
  // ...
};
```

---

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
  var showText = document.querySelector('.show-text');
  if (showText) {
    showText.addEventListener('click', () => {
      var seoText = document.querySelector('.seo-text');
      if (seoText) {
        seoText.classList.toggle('hide-before'); 
      }
    }); 
  }
});
```

Comment: @Как "на русском" в данном случае читается данная команда?

Comment: @QuickBrownFox `||` - `или`

Comment: а как, например, быть с подобным, выдает подобную ошибку, как в посте: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
document.querySelector('.show-text').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('.seo-text').classList.toggle('hide-before');
});
});`

Comment: Спасибо, увидел изменения в посте.